# Iterating Through Pandas Pivot Table and Calculating New Column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a pandas dataframe called sales_pivot that has columns customer, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, and 2022. I'd like to assign the word "Churn" to a column called "2019_udc" if a customer purchased something in 2018 and spent $0 in 2019. The other conditions are irrelevant to the error.

```
#convert deltas to new customer/upsell/downsell/churn

years = range(2019, 2022)

# dictionary of conditions for each state (new/upsell/downsell/churn)
label_mapping = {
    'Churn': ((sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}'] > 0) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] == 0)),
    'New Customer': ((sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}'] == 0) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] > 0)),
    'Upsell': (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] > sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}']),
    'Downsell': ((sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}'] > 0) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] < sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}']) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] > 0))
}

# looping through all data and adding appropriate label
for year in years:
    label_column = f'{year}_udc'
    sales_pivot[label_column] = 'None'  # Initialize the column with 'None' as a default
    for label, condition in label_mapping.items():
        sales_pivot.loc[condition, label_column] = label
```

I'm getting the error  `NameError: name 'year' is not defined` on the 'Churn' line of label_mapping. Is there a way to define this label_mapping without pandas trying to evaluate it?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341), i.e. some example data and desired output. BTW, check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: I see you accepted Nick's answer, so you could copy in that example data if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to defer evaluation of the conditions; one way to do this is to make them strings and then [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) them. For example:

```py
label_mapping = {
    'Churn': "((sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}'] > 0) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] == 0))",
    'New Customer': "((sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}'] == 0) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] > 0))",
    'Upsell': "(sales_pivot[f'{year}'] > sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}']) & (sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}'] > 0)",
    'Downsell': "((sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}'] > 0) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] < sales_pivot[f'{year - 1}']) & (sales_pivot[f'{year}'] > 0))"
}
sales_pivot = pd.DataFrame({'2018' : [500, 500, 500, 0], '2019' : [0, 100, 1000, 500] })
years = [2019]
for year in years:
    label_column = f'{year}_udc'
    sales_pivot[label_column] = 'None'  # Initialize the column with 'None' as a default
    for label, condition in label_mapping.items():
        sales_pivot.loc[eval(condition), label_column] = label
```

Output for my sample data:

```
   2018  2019      2019_udc
0   500     0         Churn
1   500   100      Downsell
2   500  1000        Upsell
3     0   500  New Customer
```

Note I had to change the `Upsell` condition so that it didn't override the `New Customer` condition.

It's [preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to avoid using `eval`:

```py
def map_label(row, year):
    if row[f'{year - 1}'] > 0 and row[f'{year}'] == 0:
        return 'Churn'
    if row[f'{year - 1}'] == 0 and row[f'{year}'] > 0:
        return 'New Customer'
    if row[f'{year}'] > row[f'{year - 1}'] and row[f'{year - 1}'] > 0:
        return 'Upsell'
    if row[f'{year - 1}'] > 0 and row[f'{year}'] < row[f'{year - 1}'] and row[f'{year}'] > 0:
        return 'Downsell'
    return 'None'

for year in years:
    label_column = f'{year}_udc'
    sales_pivot[label_column] = sales_pivot.apply(map_label, year=year, axis=1)
```

The output will be the same.